# jquery field name conflicts with jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-dialog

I am creating separate jsp files to show in jquery dialog box.
If I have one jsp page "parent.jsp". 'parent.jsp' has two child page for jquery dialog box. 'child1.jsp' and 'child2.jsp'.

If child1.jsp and child2.jsp has an element with same id for any  or any DOM obj inside those child page. Then there is conflict with the naming. Clicking a button on child1.jsp id effects child2.jsp. So to make things to work I have assign unique id for child pages.
Is there any way to resolve this?

I can provide unique Id's, but, I will be resusing my child.jsp in several pages. There might be some parent.jsp id and child id be same. I have to be extra careful about that.

Comment: " So to make things to work I have assign unique id for child pages. Is there any way to resolve this?" You got it: IDs must be UNIQUE on each html page {with the exception of iframe with other context}

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change those ids for classes, or just change the id name of those elements.

According to the W3C:

"The id selector is used to specify a style for a single, unique element."

"The class selector is used to specify a style for a group of elements. Unlike the id selector, the class selector is most often used on several elements."